# generate right triangles of different measures with an unknown data

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, syntax, visualization, drawing

hello (edited and clarified) Could you help me improve this code to generate at least 10 "slightly larger" right triangles, but with small random data between 1 and 20 on two of the sides, can be the two legs or the hypotenuse and a leg and the missing side with an "x". In addition, add to the resulting figures a typical square that indicates that it is a right triangle.

```
 triangle[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ,c_?NumericQ]:=
 Block[{x,y,pt,sqr},
 sqr=#.#&;
  pt[a1_,b1_,c1_]:=
  Reduce[sqr[{x,y}]==b1^2&&sqr[{x,y}-{a1,0}]==c1^2&&y>0,{x,y}];
 {(Polygon[{{0,0},{a,0},{x,y}}]),
  Text[Style[Framed[a,Background-> LightYellow],11],{a/2,0}],
  Text[Style[Framed[b,Background-> LightYellow],11],{x/2,y/2}],
  Text[Style[Framed[c,Background-> LightYellow],11], 
     {(a+x)/2,y/2}]}/.ToRules[pt[a,b,c]]]

  g[{s1_,s2_,s3_}]:=
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick],FaceForm[None],triangle[s1,s2,s3]},
          ImagePadding->20,ImageSize->{200,200}]


  GraphicsGrid[{
  {g[{2, 1, Sqrt[5]}], g[{1, 2, Sqrt[5]}],
  g[{Sqrt[5], 1, 2}], g[{Sqrt[5], 2, 1}]},
  {g[{2, 2, Sqrt[8]}], g[{Sqrt[8], 2, 2}],
  g[{2, Sqrt[8], 2}],
  g[{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 2}]}}]

  out put
```

[image]
desired execution

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
triangle[] := Module[{x, y, z, r, rep}, x = RandomInteger[{1, 20}];
  If[RandomInteger[{1, 2}] == 1, y = RandomInteger[{x, Min[6 x, 20]}],
    z = RandomInteger[{x + 1, Min[6 x, 20]}]];
  r = {RotationMatrix[{{-x, y}, {x, 0}}], 
     RotationMatrix[{{0, y}, {-x, 0}}], 
     IdentityMatrix[2]}[[RandomInteger[{1, 3}]]];
  {x, y, z} = ({x, y, z} /. 
     Solve[x^2 + y^2 == z^2, PositiveReals][[1]]);
  rep = {x, y, z};
  rep[[RandomInteger[{1, 3}]]] = "x";
  Graphics[{{Line[
      r . # & /@ {{Min[x, y]/10, 0}, {Min[x, y]/10, Min[x, y]/10}, {0,
          Min[x, y]/10}}]}, 
    Line[r . # & /@ {{0, 0}, {x, 0}, {0, y}, {0, 0}}], 
    Text[Style[Framed[rep[[1]], Background -> LightYellow], 10], 
     r . {x/2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[Framed[rep[[2]], Background -> LightYellow], 10], 
     r . {0, y/2}], 
    Text[Style[Framed[rep[[3]], Background -> LightYellow], 10], 
     r . ({(x y^2)/z^2 + x/2, (x^2 y)/z^2 + y/2}/2)]}, 
   ImageSize -> {200, 200}]]

GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[triangle[], 9], 3], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: azerbajdzan,exactly what i was looking for thank you. It can be done by presenting the triangles downwards, numbering them and leaving a column for their resolution.

Comment: (+1)  @padre  If the result is what your want, why not up-vote the answer and then ask another require.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't think it was necessary, because I was going to vote for 
 answer anyway, I'm sorry you thought otherwise